# Does trac have remote API?

Tags: api, trac

I know there is xmlrpc plugin for trac. But I is not my trac site nor do I have admin rights. I just have a normal user account with limited priviledges.

Beside the obvious low level of doing things (submitting requests by emulating web browser), is there a better way to do this?

I'm interested mainly in these:

- View wiki page
- Edit wiki page
- Submit new ticket
- View Ticket
- Add comment to ticket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the "functional testing" in the Trac source, you'll find that we have code that exercises Trac using [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/).  You might find that to be a useful starting point for doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Trac does not provide an API by default. You might install the [XmlRpcPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin/). Trac then provides anonymous and authenticated access to an API via two protocols: XML-RPC and JSON-RPC.

A helper library for easier access is https://github.com/jakoch/PHPTracRPC

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only way to do this would be to emulate browser.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you mean by "emulate browser" since I'm not familiar with what you are referring to.

Comment: You would need to gather exact names of the form fields, then forge a POST request using those fields (including hidden ones). Then the html page comes back and you would need to parse it for the information needed. Not very elegant. It's called webscraping.